# Rails ERB: radio_button_tag not generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I have an ERB that only contains this line:

```
hello <% radio_button_tag "a", "b" %> world
```

**PROBLEM:** Output is only `hello  world`. No radio button is generated.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forget equal sign:

```
hello <%= radio_button_tag "a", "b" %> world
```